# How to run command and detect if it's successful by C language in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

I use the code below to run a command by C in Linux, I can get only the output of this function, how can I detect if it was run successfully? Are there any return codes representing this?

```
const char * run_command(const char * command)
{

    const int BUFSIZE = 1000;

    FILE *fp;
    char buf[BUFSIZE];

    if((fp = popen(command, "r")) == NULL)
       perror("popen");
    while((fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, fp)) != NULL)
       printf("%s",buf);

    pclose(fp);

    return buf;
}
```

Comment: You have `main` return 0 to the environment for a successful run or any other number if something's gone wrong (alternatively you can call exit in other parts of a program for the same effect). Is this what you're after? Btw, that `return buf;` call will never be reached.

Comment: Why not use system() ? http://linux.die.net/man/3/system

Comment: `return buf;` after `exit(0);`?

Comment: Do you actually need the command output, or you simply need to know whether the action succeeded or not?

Comment: Also, `buf[BUFSIZE] = '\0';` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Vincent - can you get the output/return code using `system`?

Comment: Returning a `const char *` to a local array after calling `exit()`?

Comment: @KirilKirov - system() returns the status of the command. For the output I guess you can get it from the standard output.

Comment: @Vincent Because `system()` is evil and encourages lazy programming?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pclose()` returns the exit status of the program called (or -1 if wait4() failed(), see [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pclose))
So you can check:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

....

int status, code;

status = pclose( fp );
if( status != -1 ) {
    if( WIFEXITED(status) ) {  // normal exit
         code = WEXITSTATUS(status);
         if( code != 0 ) {
              // normally indicats an error
         }
    } else {
         // abnormal termination, e.g. process terminated by signal           
    }
}
```

The macros I used are described [here](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid)

Answer (score 5):

From the [`pclose(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pclose) documentation:

> The **`pclose()`** function waits for the associated process to terminate; it
>        returns the exit status of the command, as returned by [**`wait4(2)`**](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait4).

Answer (score 1):

pclose returns the exit code of the pipe.